# Eclipse didn't show Welcome page on first start

Tags: eclipse

I have createt a universal intro Page in eclipse wehen i click on Help -> Welcome it shows up. But on the firt start it didn't pop up. i have tried to add "org.eclipse.ui/SHOW_INTRO=true" or "org.eclipse.ui.workbench/WELCOME_DIALOG=true" to the plugin customization but it didn't change.

I found the solution the WorkbenchWindow has this code

```
// Hack!! don't show the intro if there's more than one open
        // perspective
        List<MPerspective> persps = modelService.findElements(model, null, MPerspective.class,
                null);
        if (persps.size() > 1) {
            PrefUtil.getAPIPreferenceStore().setValue(IWorkbenchPreferenceConstants.SHOW_INTRO,
                    false);
            PrefUtil.saveAPIPrefs();
        }
```

now i change the SHOW_INTRO to true in my WindowAdvicer.

Comment: So do you want to see it every time when start eclipse or what?

Comment: No only the first time.

Comment: I recognized if i have only one Perspective then it works.

Answer (score 0):

I've just suffered this when updating to Neon.2. In my plugin_customization.ini I had 'org.eclipse.ui/PERSPECTIVE_BAR_EXTRAS=id1, id2' which opens 2 perspectives. This feature had not been working prior to Neon, but was fixed for Neon (Bug 479126 - PERSPECTIVE_BAR_EXTRAS setting not taken into account). This and the combination of the "Hack" the OP found causes SHOW_INTRO to be set false.
Solution is to remove PERSPECTIVE_BAR_EXTRAS pref.